# Повторный вызов функции после .then

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть функция возвращающая объект Promise и загружающая файлы через api vk. Как сделать так, чтобы после удачного выполнения .then() она вызвалась повторно бесконечное число раз. С рекурсией стек переполнится, а что сделать не знаю. 
Следующая загрузка должна быть только по завершению предыдущей.

```js
upload(files).then();
```

Comment: Когда выполняется then, в стеке только одна функция — собственно та, которую вызывает then. Никакого переполнения не будет

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! а как тогда сделать?  если в then помещу её же, то она только 2 раза вызовется

Comment: Код `function x(){Promise.resolve().then(function(){   console.log((new Error()).stack);x(); }   );}` и последующий вызов `x()` ушёл в бесконечность и повесил вкладку, но стек не переполнился :) Вот и вы по аналогии можете сделать, по вкусу можно паузу через `setTimeout` добавить